# Pass argument to reactjs click handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question about passing arguments to React click handlers. 
I have the following code, but for some reason the node argument is not passed to the toggle function. Shouldn't it? It's defined this way because it's a recursive component.

```
var Element = React.createClass({

    toggle: function(e,node){

    },

    render: function(){

        var nodes = this.props.children.map(function(n){

                return <Element node={n} text={n.text} children={n.children}  />

        });

        return (
               <span onClick={this.toggle.bind(this,this.props.node)}>{this.props.text}</span>

        );
    }

});
```

Comment: I'm don't fully understand why you even bind on `this.props.node`. You can just access `this.props.node` in the toggle method.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can follow. You're assigning your the result of your call to map to a nodes variable which you then never use. I don't understand what this code is supposed to do or achieve.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`Function.prototype.bind` bind arguments beginning from left. The correct way to receive the node argument is to look for it at the very left position of the argument list:

```
toggle: function(node, event) {
  console.log('node', node);
  console.log('event', event);
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8xxfgce7/ for an example.

Comment: You must be doing something different wrong, this works perfectly fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8xxfgce7/

Comment: You can totally set the value of a property to a different node, even in a map. The problem here is that you don't actually render the `nodes` array. There's a whole bunch of things wrong with your code. The canonical way of assigning to this.props.children, is to pass the nodes as children (`<Parent><Child /><Child /></Parent>`). Assigning to `children` property like `<Parent children={[<Child />, <Child />]} />` may work, but is not the canonical way. Also, once you actually start rendering `nodes` your code will end in a stack overflow because the recursion never breaks.

Comment: I found the problem. It was caused by an unrelated error. My bad

Comment: I agree. I accidental removed too much of the code from the actual code to illustrate the real problem. It actually composed as parent - > child components and the model will prevent stackoverflow because the leaf nodes have empty child arrays

Comment: Is it possible to pass 2 parameters with this method?

Comment: @ibiza Yes, just bind multiple arguments, e.g. `aFunction.bind(this, argument1, argument2)`

Comment: This will create a new function on each render no? that will impact performance allot.

Answer (score 0):

While the above answer is correct. Here is another example how to pass both **event** and **parameter** to `onClick` function.

Your event firing element e.g a button:

```
<button onClick={this.editTask.bind(this, item._id)}>
  Edit item
</button>
```

Event handler function:

```
editItem(id, event) {
  event.preventDefault() // Prevents default form submission
  console.log('id: ', id) // Prints the item id 
  .
  .
  .
}
```